# Array Adapter is not functioning Correctly

Tags: android, arrays, android-arrayadapter

I am using an array adapter to populate a listview from user input. The array adpter will not work however and crashes the app. I don't no why it does this and I would appreciate if anyone could explain why. Below is my class and the error I get.

My Class

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddScore extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView lv;
    private EditText player;
    private EditText description;
    private EditText winner;
    private EditText game;
    private Button btn3;
    private String TAG = "Hannah";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_score);
        // MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        player = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player);
        description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.description);
        winner = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.winner);
        game = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.game);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);


        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View view) {
                List<String> sLog = new ArrayList<>();
                MySQLiteHelper Helper = new MySQLiteHelper(view.getContext());
                List sLogs = Helper.getAllScores();
                sLog.add(player.getText().toString().trim());
                sLog.add(description.getText().toString().trim());
                sLog.add(winner.getText().toString().trim());
                sLog.add(game.getText().toString().trim());


                for (int i = 0; i < sLog.size(); i++) {
                    Score score = new Score();
                    sLog.add(score.toString());
                }

                //ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sLog);
                Log.d(TAG, "**************************");
                lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                Score score = new Score();
                arrayAdapter.add(String.valueOf(score));

                Toast.makeText(AddScore.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Error
Error:(62, 53) error: cannot infer type arguments for ArrayAdapter<>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because using only `this` refers to `View.OnClickListener` class not `activity` class. And `ArrayAdapter<>` requires `context` as first argument which can be provided here by `activity` and not `View.OnClickListener`.

So try like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(AddScore.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sLog);
Log.d(TAG, "**************************");
lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sLog);
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sLog);
```

You need to pass the context. As this is inside a closure, you need to explicitly `getActivity()` as `this` will be not get you the context.